# Typescript error in Angular 5 project prod build

Tags: angular5

When I building my angular 5 project using

```
ng build --prod
```

It gives typescript error as below.

```
ERROR in Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at Object.getEffectiveTypeAnnotationNode (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:9341:18)
at assignContextualParameterTypes (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41652:25)
at checkFunctionExpressionOrObjectLiteralMethod (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:41948:29)
at checkExpressionWorker (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42959:28)
at checkExpression (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42898:42)
at checkBinaryLikeExpression (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42475:29)
at checkBinaryExpression (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42467:20)
at checkExpressionWorker (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42980:28)
at checkExpression (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42898:42)
at checkBinaryLikeExpression (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42475:29)
at checkBinaryExpression (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42467:20)
at checkExpressionWorker (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42980:28)
at checkExpression (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:42898:42)
at checkExpressionStatement (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:44962:13)
at checkSourceElement (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:46746:28)
at Object.forEach (E:\Files\dash-functional\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:1506:30)
```

node version - 8.11.1
How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

i have resolved this problem by upgrading typescript to latest version.